# How to set Twitter share link url parameter with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter

I want to create Tweet button which share a page link. Everything is pretty fine and easy. The problem is that i use AngularJS which generate link with parameters for me.

Here is my HTML

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{{userInfo.MovieUrl}}">Tweet</a>
```

and of course JS

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

I get this from https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet

How can i set this url parameter with angular ?

Comment: This is done here at StackOverflow when you want to share the question with someone who can answer/help. My approach is the same.